# ohotfix log files in windows XP...need them?

Tags: windows-xp

Does one need to keep the ohotfix(***)_msi.log files in XP? They take up a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are just like any other (installation) log files that are mostly used to troubleshoot installation errors. So, if everything went OK when installing the updates I'd remove them without much further thought.

<sub>OTOH, on modern disk sizes, the space they occupy shouldn't be *that much* of an issue...</sub>

Comment: Thanks Jawa! Yea, I wouldn't call the office machines here very 'modern' unfortunately. ;)